# How can I hide the command prompt in my FWT application?

Tags: command-line, fantom

I'm creating an FWT application in [Fantom](http://fantom.org/), and every time I run my application, the MS-DOS command prompt window appears (as well as my main application form).

I don’t want this MS-DOS window to be shown. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions were suggested over at fantom.org:

http://fantom.org/sidewalk/topic/780

Comment: FYI - Fan changed names to Fantom shortly after the original question: http://fantom.org/sidewalk/topic/821